# Guzzle POST HTTPS requests return 403 Forbidden only when called inside PHPUnit tests

Tags: 8, testing, http-request

On one side I have a remote Drupal 8 (8.8.1) served via HTTPS which has the following endpoint:

```
MODULENAME.get_notify:
  path: 'MODULENAME/get-notify'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\MODULENAME\Controller\MODULENAMEApiController::get_notify'
    _title: 'Get notification'
  methods:  [POST]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

On the client side I have a Drupal 8 (8.8.2) served via HTTPS which sends a notification using Guzzle library. This Drupal is local to my machine and is served via DDEV. Here is the Guzzle petition which is located in a custom module:

```
$options = [
  'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
  'json' => $jsonArray,
  'timeout' => 15,
];
$response = $this->httpClient->post($url, $options);
```

The system works well except that when running PHPUnit tests (BrowserTestBase) of the involved module the POST query always return the following error:

```
Client error: `POST https://SERVER_DOMAIN/MODULENAME/get-notify` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response'
```

Any idea why I get this error message?

Comment: Are you sure SERVER_DOMAIN resolves to the remote host address and not somewhere else in your containerized DDEV environment?

Is there a reason you're not mocking your HTTP client/requests for the unit test? What's being tested in the unit test?

Comment: Yes, If i do a ping inside DDEV machine or in host machine the result is the same: the server side responds. Also, If I do the same POST request which is done in tested function via terminal curl request, it works fine in both DDEV and host machine. In this unit test I send a notification with some data and I expect an OK response from the server side. The code which sends the POST request is inside a function which is part of a service declared on MODULENAME.services.yml.